# How to set the syntax language for a specific file in atom?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

Atom does not recognize that a file should be a shell script and defaults to plain text syntax. I can change it in the bottom right corner but the next time I open the file I have to change it again. How can I set the file to open with the correct syntax?

I found a atom package that would do this but it is unmaintained and no longer works: https://github.com/blezek/file-mode

You can set the atom defaults so that it opens anything it doesn't recognize as a shell script, but then if there's a file that should be plain text it will open as a shell script so doing it on a per file basis would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found for shell scripts specifically is adding a file identifier to the top line. I'm still not sure how to set the file type for any file in general.

```
#!/bin/bash
```